# Export gglot to multiple excel workbook

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that has been exported to multiple Excel Workbooks based on it's filter and now I would like to export the graphs I have created into their respective workbook on another sheet.

```
#Create Dataframe
df = data.frame(Year = c(2018,2019,2020,2018,2019,2020,2018,2019,2020),
                Country = c("Germany","Germany","Germany", "Japan", "Japan", "Japan",  "Thailand", "Thailand", "Thailand"), 
                Count = c(17, 15, 60, 23, 25, 60, 50, 18, 31))

#Graph
df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x= Year, y = Count, color = Country)) +
    geom_line()

#Separate the dataframe according to their respective country
splitdf = split(df, df$Country)

#Export to xlsx
lapply( split(df, df$Country), function(x) {xlsx::write.xlsx(x,
                                                             file=paste0(x$Country[1],".xlsx"), col.names=TRUE, 
                                                             row.names=FALSE, append=FALSE, showNA=TRUE, 
                                                             password= "test")})
```

Essentially this is how I want my desired output to look like:
[image]

So all of the files exported should have their individual line chart line exported in this manner

```
df %>%
  filter(Country == "Japan") %>% #Their respective country
    ggplot(aes(x= Year, y = Count, color = Country)) +
    geom_line()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `openxlsx` package is good for rendering in Excel. There are lots of examples and tutorials online. You can also check out [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/vignettes/Formatting.html) vignette for various functions.

Here's an example

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()
mySheet <- addWorksheet(wb, "Chart")

ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) +
  geom_point()
insertPlot(wb, mySheet) # Will add the current plot

openXL(wb)  # preview the Excel file
```